# Get accumulated data by dates in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I need to get accumulated number of users by a range of dates i.e. for a month by date. The following query works fine but I have to run it for each date and I cannot use group by date. Please advise.

1. MySQL version 8
2. Sample Data

```
+------------------------+
| id | Registration_Date |
+------------------------+
| 1  | 2020-05-01        | 
| 2  | 2020-05-01        |
| 3  | 2020-05-02        |
| 4  | 2020-05-03        |
| 5  | 2020-05-04        |
+------------------------+
```

3. Current Query

```
SELECT COUNT(id) AS 'Registrations'
FROM users
WHERE DATE(Registration_Date) <= "2020-05-04";
```

4. Desired Result

```
+-----------------------------------+
| Registration_Date | Registrations |
+-----------------------------------+
| 2020-05-01        | 2             |
| 2020-05-02        | 3             |
| 2020-05-03        | 4             |
| 2020-05-04        | 5             |
+-----------------------------------+
```

Comment: Can you please include sample data from which you derived the results?

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Comment: Why can't you group by date?

Comment: @zedfoxus I have added sample data

Comment: @Nick It's version 8 of MySQL

Comment: @kmoser `GROUP BY` gets daily registrations but I need accumulated numbers as on every date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use window functions to achieve the result you want, `COUNT`ing `id` values on or before the current registration date. Note we use `DISTINCT` to avoid duplication of entries where multiple users register on the same day:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Registration_Date,
       COUNT(id) OVER (ORDER BY Registration_Date) AS Registrations
FROM users
```

Output:

```
Registration_Date   Registrations
2020-05-01          2
2020-05-02          3
2020-05-03          4
2020-05-04          5
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xeCj1Jk1xQrQ2Mdp4x816S/3)

To deal with the case where there are registrations before the first reporting date of interest, you need to count registrations up to and including the first date and then for each date in the reporting period in a derived table, and then sum those in an outer query:

```
SELECT Reporting_Date,
       SUM(Registrations) OVER (ORDER BY Reporting_Date) AS Registrations
FROM (
  SELECT '2020-05-01' AS Reporting_Date, COUNT(id) AS Registrations
  FROM users
  WHERE Registration_Date <= '2020-05-01'
  UNION 
  SELECT Registration_Date, COUNT(id)
  FROM users
  WHERE Registration_Date BETWEEN '2020-05-02' AND '2020-05-04'
  GROUP BY Registration_Date
) r
```

Generating the result this way in general will be more efficient than wrapping the original query as a derived table as it will require fewer aggregations.

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xeCj1Jk1xQrQ2Mdp4x816S/3)

Comment: Can you explain how this manages to only count values on or before the current registration date, without any obvious use of `<=`? I see the `ORDER BY` but it's not clear to me how this accomplishes that condition.

Comment: @kmoser as described in the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-frames.html), in the absence of a frame clause, but with an order by clause, the range of a window function is "BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW"

Comment: @Nick it works. To get grand total until the first reporting date, I modified it a little bit and posted for others.

Answer (score 1):

I used [Nick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61649598/2838908)'s answer as source and now modified it a bit to get grand total plus daily increment value.

```
SELECT Reporting_Date, Registrations FROM

(SELECT DISTINCT DATE(Registration_Date) AS Reporting_Date,
       COUNT(id) OVER (ORDER BY DATE(Registration_Date)) AS Registrations
FROM users) AS RAW_Result

WHERE Reporting_Date BETWEEN "2020-05-01" AND "2020-05-04";
```

Result:

```
+-----------------------------------+
| Registration_Date | Registrations |
+-----------------------------------+
| 2020-05-01        | 1200          | (grand total until this date)
| 2020-05-02        | 1201          | (grand total + daily increment) 
| 2020-05-03        | 1202          |
| 2020-05-04        | 1203          |
+-----------------------------------+
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't consider this scenario as it wasn't in the question. This will work, but as the table gets bigger you will probably find the query in my edited answer to be more efficient. Still a useful answer, +1

Comment: Thank you very much, Sir. I highly appreciate it.